# Where can I find a documentation or sample code about tkinter for python 3.2?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.2

Or website of sample codes regarding tkinter for python 3.2 will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [the Tkinter page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) on the python wiki . This has a lot of references about where to get material for tkinter

Answer (score 0):

The site [tkdocs.com](http://tkdocs.com) has a lot of examples.